# What to do when I find myself "over-casting"?

Tags: java, string, casting, swt, long-integer

I am in the midst of adding a somewhat simple functionality to a GUI project at my work and I feel like I am having to cast too much [and therefore use too many variables/changing of types]. You can type cast too much, right? How can I go about solving the issue without over-casting? This is a part of my dilemma:

I am given a long -> 110614173509 which I need in the end to display as such -> November 6, 2014 5:35:09 PM .

How I am implementing it now is as such:

```
double second, minute, hour;

second = time % 100;
minute = (Math.floor(time/100))%100;
```

Then to display it within my tree [SWT], I will have to setText as a String. It just seems crazy to me, to go from long to double, to string, etc. Is this just how it is sometimes or can I step back and look at it differently?

Comment: Why are you choosing to use doubles rather than ints for second, minute, and hour?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do the hard work of converting a `long` to a `String` date manually? There's the `SimpleDateFormat` class that you can use:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, YYYY HH:mm:ss aaa");
System.out.println(format.format(new Date(110614173509l)));
```

Output:

> July 04, 1973 07:09:33 AM

Comment: Well that surpasses my questions even! Thanks. Would you have another answer for more general situations about when someone finds themselves casting too much? (Or would your answer be there are usually other ways to take care of the problem, e.g. SimpleDateFormat for this example)

Comment: @triforceofcourage In many cases where you tend to cast a lot there are probably easier ways to do it in general. However, this always depends on what you're actually doing and is hard to say in general. In your question the step to a `double` isn't necessary. You can stay in the `long` domain or even go to an `int` if the range allows it. However, `long` -> `String` is the minimum you can achieve here.